# Try jitsi meet with raspberry pi

Tags: webrtc, raspberry-pi3, jitsi

I tried to use jitsi meet for video conference on raspberry.
First, I use the public server at https://meet.jit.si/ to create a room and joins to that room from my raspberry pi 3 board. I have a picam camera v1 plug in to pi board and an external usb speaker.
Second, I use chromium-browser to join the meeting from raspberry and the preview video looks good. After that, I join that room from my pc using chrome browser then I notice the video is lagged and sluggish on both preview (on raspberry) and the peer (PC browser).
I think the bottleneck is network so I tried to host jitsi meet to one of my PC running ubuntu 16.04 and the result is the same.

I do think that Jitsi Meet implements SFU by videobridge so it should not affect the performance of preview in local browser.

Have anyone success with jitsi meet on raspberry with HD 720p for video conferencing ?
Any recommendations are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: As of today, any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite possible the lag is due to the encoding, do you know if the pi3 can encode vp8 efficiently?  You might try it with h264 instead and see if that makes any difference, I think pi has hw acceleration for that. 
 You can try this by setting 'preferH264' in config.js to true (make sure to verify in the sdp that h264 is preferred)

Jitsi also supports direct p2p calls for conferences with only 2 participants, so you can eliminate the bridge altogether if you think it's causing problems.